# (In R) How to split words by title case in a string like "WeLiveInCA" into "We Live In CA" while preserving abbreviations?

Tags: r, regex, string, split

(In R) How to split words by title case in a string like "WeLiveInCA" into "We Live In CA" without splitting abbreviations?

I know how to split the string at every uppercase letter, but doing that would split initialisms/abbreviations, like `CA` or `USSR` or even `U.S.A.` and I need to preserve those.

So I'm thinking some type of logical like `if a word in a string isn't an initialism then split the word with a space where a lowercase character is followed by an uppercase character`.

My snippet of code below splits words with spaces by capital letters, but it breaks initialisms like `CA` becomes `C A` undesirably.

```
s <- "WeLiveInCA"
trimws(gsub('([[:upper:]])', ' \\1', s))
# "We Live In C A"
```

or another example...

```
s <- c("IDon'tEatKittensFYI", "YouKnowYourABCs")
trimws(gsub('([[:upper:]])', ' \\1', s))
# "I Don't Eat Kittens F Y I" "You Know Your A B Cs"
```

The results I'd want would be:

```
"We Live In CA"
#
"I Don't Eat Kittens FYI" "You Know Your ABCs"
```

But this needs to be widely applicable (not just for my example)

Comment: How do you tell the difference between `IDon't` and `ABCs`? Why break `I` and `Don't`?

Comment: `gsub("((?<=^[A-Z])(?=[A-Z]))|(?<=[^A-Z])(?=[A-Z])", " ", s, perl=TRUE)` ; this splits things like *IDon't* if at the start of the string but won;t catch things like *Don'tILike*

Answer (score 2):

Try with base R `gregexpr/regmatches`.

```
s <- c("WeLiveInCA", "IDon'tEatKittensFYI", "YouKnowYourABCs")
regmatches(s, gregexpr('[[:upper:]]+[^[:upper:]]*', s))
#[[1]]
#[1] "We"   "Live" "In"   "CA"  
#
#[[2]]
#[1] "IDon't"  "Eat"     "Kittens" "FYI"    
#
#[[3]]
#[1] "You"  "Know" "Your" "ABCs"
```

Explanation.

1. `[[:upper:]]+` matches one or more upper case letters;
2. `[^[:upper:]]*` matches zero or more occurrences of anything but upper case letters.
3. In sequence these two regular expressions match words starting with upper case letter(s) followed by something else.

Comment: This is a good start but it does not answer the OP question. For example, *U.S.A.* does not work in your example. Neither does *IDon'tKnow*

Comment: @DevGin Thanks. The pattern `'[[:upper:]][[:upper:][:punct:]]*[^[:upper:]]*'` gets *U.S.A.* but not *IDon't*, like I said in the comment to the question. I am still waiting for an answer from the OP on that one.